# Problem when displaying frames with OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, camera, video-capture

**Hello,**

I use my RaspberryPi Camera Module v2.1 and my Jetson Nano with Python to capture frames with the camera and displaying them creating a sort of "video stream". But my question is rather about the usage of OpenCV than about the hardware I use.
My code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imshow
import time

def gstreamer_pipeline (capture_width=3280, capture_height=2464, display_width=1280, display_height=720, framerate=21, flip_method=0) :   
    return ('nvarguscamerasrc ! ' 
    'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), '
    'width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, '
    'format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! '
    'nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! '
    'video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! '
    'videoconvert ! '
    'video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink'  % (capture_width,capture_height,framerate,flip_method,display_width,display_height))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_pipeline(flip_method=0), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

    if cap.isOpened():
        try:
            while cap.isOpened():
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Stopped video streaming.")
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print("Unable to open camera.")
```

I'm reading the capture device, apply a color conversion to RGB for each frame and want to display it with `cv2.imshow('frame',frame)` as I have seen in tutorials. The problem is that this code won't do anything, I get no window and no error message.
The output generated by the program:

```
GST_ARGUS: Creating output stream
CONSUMER: Waiting until producer is connected...
GST_ARGUS: Available Sensor modes :
GST_ARGUS: 3264 x 2464 FR = 21.000000 fps Duration = 47619048 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 3264 x 1848 FR = 28.000001 fps Duration = 35714284 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 1920 x 1080 FR = 29.999999 fps Duration = 33333334 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 1280 x 720 FR = 59.999999 fps Duration = 16666667 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: 1280 x 720 FR = 120.000005 fps Duration = 8333333 ; Analog Gain range min 1.000000, max 10.625000; Exposure Range min 13000, max 683709000;

GST_ARGUS: Running with following settings:
   Camera index = 0 
   Camera mode  = 0 
   Output Stream W = 3264 H = 2464 
   seconds to Run    = 0 
   Frame Rate = 21.000000 
GST_ARGUS: PowerService: requested_clock_Hz=37126320
GST_ARGUS: Setup Complete, Starting captures for 0 seconds
GST_ARGUS: Starting repeat capture requests.
CONSUMER: Producer has connected; continuing.
Gtk-Message: 21:05:04.463: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

After the loading error (which occurs often; the program is still running) it does just nothing until I cancel with CTRL+C. If I replace the `cv2.imshow` with a simple `imshow(frame)` by SciPy however, it is normally working and outputting images, so I think the problems lie rather in OpenCV than in my camera.
Any idea what I do wrong and how to get a constant (>=21FPS) stream of frames to work?

*Thanks for the answers in advance!*

Comment: You must have `waitKey()` after `imshow()`. OpenCV updates the screen while waiting for a keypress.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply! It's solved now